# Profiles in spring-security saml sample

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml, opensaml, oasis

I am stuck in understanding how the authentication request is being passed, in the sample application provided online https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml As the authentication request generated is using default profile, If anyone can give an idea on how to use other profiles published by OASIS. My use case is somewhat like what is defined in this blog http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.in/2012/02/implementing-saml-to-xacml.html